# Can you help me parse out some pipe delimited values

Tags: formula

I have this string that I need to parse out values using a formula field. I have working examples from values 1 , 2 and 3 but I can't see the pattern within these to extend to values 4 , 5 and 6 in the string.  Would appreciate any kind of guidance even if its just breaking down the code so I can modify it that is , explaining what's happening.

Article | Onsite | Sponsorship | Editorial | TFK Kid of the year | Standard

Value 1

`TRIM(LEFT(AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c , FIND("|", AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c )-1))`

Value 2

`LEFT(RIGHT(AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c , LEN(AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c ) - FIND ("|", AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c )), FIND("|" , RIGHT(AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c , LEN(AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c ) - FIND ("|", AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c )))-1)`

Value three

`LEFT(RIGHT(AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c , LEN(RIGHT(AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c , LEN(AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c ) - FIND ("|", AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c ))) - FIND ("|", RIGHT(AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c , LEN(AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c ) - FIND ("|", AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c )))), FIND("|" , RIGHT(AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c , LEN(RIGHT(AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c , LEN(AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c ) - FIND ("|", AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c ))) - FIND ("|", RIGHT(AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c , LEN(AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c ) - FIND ("|", AB2__ABMediaElementPath__c )))))-1)`

Comment: Any chance you can modify the underlying data/storage format? Pipe delimiting is not a great solution - if you have the opportunity to convert that data into a junction object structure, checkboxes, or even a multi-select picklist, you get more and better tools to work with it.

Comment: No. Its a third party data syndicator. That's how things come in at least for now.

Comment: So... you want to parse the string and then do what? Have you defined several different formula fields each to get a part of the string? Also, as the data comes in, do you have any opportunity to modify it then?

Comment: Keep in mind a formula field may exceed the compiled size limit (especially if you have to deal with more values), in which case you'll have to write Apex or Flow anyway.

Comment: There will be six fields. Each with the formula for the place holder. These value have a specific business definition. ALl I wan to do is groups reports by each of these values.